# jQuery on.change specific element of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

I'm currently struggling with my specific problem. I'm using Symfony Collection entity type and https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/ bundle for front-end render. When I click to add a new collection, the new set of input is rendered. I need to hide a specific inputs when a condition is not met. To do that I'm using jQuery. At the start I declare an array of possible HTML ids.

```
var regularityWeeksArray = [
    '#user_working_hours_weeks_0_regularity', '#user_working_hours_weeks_1_regularity',
    '#user_working_hours_weeks_2_regularity', '#user_working_hours_weeks_3_regularity'
]
```

Then I join it for jQuery's requirements, because I didnt figured out how to workaround that. I would love to use this code to run that, but I need to get which specific element of an array is being changed to give my function ID of the element. Now I'm changing the first one, because I don't know how to meet my requirements.

```
var regularityWeeksArrayToString = regularityWeeksArray.join(', ');

$(document).on('change', regularityWeeksArrayToString, function() {
    if($(this).val() === 'interim'){
        showInterimWithID(0);
    } else {
        hideInterimWithID(0);
    }
});
```

Do you have any ideas how to do this? Thanks a lot in advance, I'm really losing my hair for couple of hours now.

//EDIT: for context, this is how showsInterimWithID() looks like, it shows specific inputs and its labels.

```
function showInterimWithID(id){
    $('#user_working_hours_weeks_'+ id +'_interim_from, label[for=user_working_hours_weeks_'+ id +'_interim_from]').show();
    $('#user_working_hours_weeks_'+ id +'_interim_to, label[for=user_working_hours_weeks_'+ id +'_interim_to]').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.id` is the ID of the target of the event. You can get its index in the array.

```
$(document).on('change', regularityWeeksArrayToString, function() {
    var index = regularityWeeksArray.indexOf(this.id);
    if($(this).val() === 'interim'){
        showInterimWithID(index);
    } else {
        hideInterimWithID(index);
    }
});
```